# Multiple joins on same table using different join criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have four tables in a project I'm working on and I'm trying to sum up data twice from one of the tables and I cannot seem to get the joins working properly.

auth_users

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | fname |  lname  |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 | Frank | Testing |
| 12 | Bill  | Smith   |
|  1 | Bob   | Testing |
+----+-------+---------+
```

tblclocktime

```
+----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| id | employeeid |          clockin           |          clockout          |
+----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 68 |          1 | 2020-10-12 13:02:58.063-04 | 2020-10-12 13:04:02.034-04 |
| 69 |          1 | 2020-10-12 13:05:55.308-04 | 2020-10-12 13:06:40.819-04 |
| 70 |          1 | 2020-10-12 13:06:58.471-04 | 2020-10-12 15:53:00.95-04  |
| 71 |          1 | 2020-10-12 15:58:58.941-04 | 2020-10-12 16:59:12.911-04 |
+----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

tblpersonaltime

```
+----+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| id | empid | typeid |         starttime          |          endtime           |
+----+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:11:44.396-04 | 2020-10-12 15:15:54.739-04 |
|  2 |     1 |      2 | 2020-10-12 15:16:04.371-04 | 2020-10-12 15:24:44.908-04 |
|  3 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:25:00.448-04 | 2020-10-12 15:26:12.022-04 |
|  4 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:26:22.19-04  | 2020-10-12 15:26:29.161-04 |
|  5 |     1 |      2 | 2020-10-12 15:26:29.161-04 | 2020-10-12 15:26:34.814-04 |
|  6 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:29:43.067-04 | 2020-10-12 15:29:45.976-04 |
|  7 |     1 |      2 | 2020-10-12 15:29:46.915-04 | 2020-10-12 15:29:48.004-04 |
|  8 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:36:18.012-04 | 2020-10-12 15:36:22.747-04 |
|  9 |     1 |      2 | 2020-10-12 15:36:23.515-04 | 2020-10-12 15:36:27.146-04 |
| 10 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:42:48.807-04 | 2020-10-12 15:45:20.393-04 |
| 11 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:45:40.426-04 | 2020-10-12 15:45:47.72-04  |
| 12 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:48:34.455-04 | 2020-10-12 15:49:15.324-04 |
| 13 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:51:13.599-04 | 2020-10-12 15:51:28.583-04 |
| 14 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:52:51.958-04 | 2020-10-12 15:53:00.945-04 |
| 15 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 15:59:00.21-04  | 2020-10-12 16:09:17.493-04 |
| 16 |     1 |      2 | 2020-10-12 16:09:26.784-04 | 2020-10-12 16:11:03.052-04 |
| 17 |     1 |      1 | 2020-10-12 16:16:11.619-04 | 2020-10-12 16:59:13.625-04 |
+----+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

tblpersonaltype

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| id |   type   | paid  | break |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Break    | true  | true  |
|  2 | Lunch    | false | true  |
|  3 | Vacation | false | false |
|  4 | Sick     | false | false |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

I'm trying to get for each clockin/clockout event the total paid and unpaid time that the employee took during that period.

Currently using this query

```
SELECT tc.id,
       tc.employeeid,
       tc.clockin,
       tc.clockout,
       sum(pt.endtime-pt.starttime) AS BREAK
FROM tblclocktime tc
JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM tblpersonaltime pt
   JOIN tblpersonaltype ptype ON pt.typeid = ptype.id
   WHERE ptype.break = TRUE
     AND ptype.paid = FALSE ) pt ON (tc.employeeid = empid
                                     AND pt.starttime BETWEEN tc.clockin AND tc.clockout)
WHERE tc.clockin BETWEEN '2020-10-11' AND '2020-10-17'
GROUP BY tc.id,
         tc.employeeid,
         tc.clockin,
         tc.clockout
ORDER BY tc.clockin
```

to generate a query result that gives the the not-paid break time that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+
| id | employeeid |          clockin           |          clockout          |    break     |
+----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+
| 70 |          1 | 2020-10-12 13:06:58.471-04 | 2020-10-12 15:53:00.95-04  | 00:08:50.91  |
| 71 |          1 | 2020-10-12 15:58:58.941-04 | 2020-10-12 16:59:12.911-04 | 00:01:36.268 |
+----+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+
```

What I cannot figure out how to do is re-join to the tblpersonaltime table to get the break but paid time. I've tried adding another join in there but I just end up with a bunch of duplicate rows.

Any ideas?

I'm trying to avoid using the business side of the project to generate the data. I'd rather it be in a query if possible. The database I'm using is Postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Use a filter expression to split the break time into `paid` and `unpaid`:

```
SELECT tc.id,
       tc.employeeid,
       tc.clockin,
       tc.clockout,
       sum(pt.endtime-pt.starttime) FILTER (WHERE pt.paid) AS BREAK_PAID,
       sum(pt.endtime-pt.starttime) FILTER (WHERE not pt.paid) AS BREAK_UNPAID,
       sum(pt.endtime-pt.starttime) AS TOTAL_BREAK
FROM tblclocktime tc
     LEFT JOIN tblpersonaltime pt
            ON pt.starttime between tc.clockin and tc.clockout
           AND pt.break
WHERE tc.clockin BETWEEN '2020-10-11' AND '2020-10-17'
GROUP BY tc.id,
         tc.employeeid,
         tc.clockin,
         tc.clockout
ORDER BY tc.clockin
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm just a mediocre SQL guy trying to gather data for SCADA reporting and this is a much needed lesson in aggregates. I appreciate your help.